# how do I fix type mismatch: @ExtendWith(SpringExtension::class) KClass -> Class in intelij?

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, kotlin, junit5

I'm using intellij community 2018.2 and gradle 4.9 with kotlin 1.2.60

I've just downloaded a springboot2 pack from start.spring.io with kotlin/gradle support + web + h2 + jpa. I am following [this](https://spring.io/blog/2018/05/11/new-tutorial-about-spring-boot-and-kotlin) official tutorial from spring.

`gradle build` and `gradle test` both work fine in command line.

In intellij though, I get the following error from the IDE:

```
Error:(9, 13) Kotlin: Type mismatch: inferred type is    KClass<SpringExtension> but Class was expected

package org.ninrod.blog.blog

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension::class) <-- RIGHT HERE
@SpringBootTest
class BlogApplicationTests {
    @Test
    fun contextLoads() {
    } 
}
```

here is the full source code of the sample: [link](https://github.com/ninrod/kotlin-springboot2).

How would one fix this in intellij so that the project compiles cleanly as in command line?

ps: here is a screenshot of the problem in intellij:

[image: screenshot: build error -> type mismatch kclass -> class]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, I uninstalled absolutely everything regarding java and then I installed everything from zero, removed all configurations, everything. Then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is correct. I could not reproduce the error as shown in the screenshot below. And I was able to run your test without issue. So it is a false error. You can verify this by confirming the project builds via Gradle either from within IDEA of from the command prompt.

Try the following:

1. From the Gradle tool window, click the "Refresh all Gradle projects" button

   - From what I am seeing, and from my experience, I don't think think this will resolve the issue. But it is a quick hit and worth a wuick try.
2. It's possible the IntelliJ IDEA caches are corrupted. Go to *File > Invalidate Caches / Restart *. In the dialog window, click "Invalidate and Restart". After IDEA restarts and the project opens, wait for it to finish reindexing the project (watch the progress at the bottom). Once the reindex is done, see if the issue is resolved.

   - I suspect this will resolve the issue.
3. If the above does not work, then it's possible something is not configured correctly. Try recreating the IDEA project. Close the project, delete (or archive) the `.idea` directory and any `*.iml` files. Then import the project by selecting the `build.gradle` file. If you are not familiar with this, watch the "[Working with Gradle in IntelliJ IDEA](https://youtu.be/JwPYjnhah3g)"  video on the IntelliJ [IDEA documentation page](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/documentation/)
4. Lastly, make sure you are running the latest version of IntelliJ IDEA (v2018.2), that was released two weeks ago. It is what I'm running. You using a lot of the latest and greatest tech (JUnit 5, Kotlin, Spring boot 2.x with Spring 5.x), so an older version of IDEA *may* have a problems. Finally, even though what you have worked for me, I'd recommend upgrading to the latest version of Kotlin (v1.2.60) in your gradle.properties

I do not get the error and can run the test:
[image]

Comment: strangelly, I performed all 4 steps and still am getting the error. It is also strange that I can run the test from the IDE, but I get the compilation error anyway. I filled a bug in the intellij issue tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-196785